# Creating a ref to Line chart using react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a ref to the chart I'm building with `chart.js` and `react-chartjs-2`.

Here's the line where I'm trying to create the ref specifying the type: `const chartRef = useRef<Line>(null);`

And this is the error I get:

```
'Line' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Line'?
```

I found the following [documentation](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/faq/typescript) but since I'm new to TypeScript I don't know how to interpret it yet. Here's the complete code I'm using:

```js
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "chart.js";
import { useRef } from "react";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "First dataset",
      data: [33, 53, 85, 41, 44, 65],
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)"
    },
    {
      label: "Second dataset",
      data: [33, 25, 35, 51, 54, 76],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#742774"
    }
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  const chartRef = useRef<Line>(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is a chart.</h1>
      <Line data={data} ref={chartRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with ChartJS, but when I changed your existing code from `const chartRef = useRef<Line>(null);` to `const chartRef = useRef<'line'>(null);` (per the docs), the linter gave me a better idea as to the what needed to be fixed (on the `ref`).

[image: Linter Error]

In your case:

```
export function App() {
  const chartRef = useRef<ChartJS<"line", number[], string>>(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is a chart.</h1>
      <Line data={data} ref={chartRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-buck-7y2cs8?file=/App.tsx)

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer!  Would you please provide the link to the documentation you mentioned?

Comment: @cBlaine It's been a while since I've looked at this, but from what I can remember I *think* it was https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/components/chart for `ChartTypeRegistry` that lead me to  https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/9871aaa2628e47d1b8bf454a3d29b2cb0232b046/types/index.d.ts for the actual registry keys.